# Friend System Posts Error

Tags: php

I'm creating a social network and you can add friends and post things, etc. When you add a friend, it inserts it into a database, in a column call friends. For example if I had Harry and Ron as friends, in the database it would come out as this.

Friends
Harry, Ron

Now, when a user posts things it will post to all your friends.You can view the posts. Viewing works fine if you have one friend, but if you have more than one, it won't work, because the php code would look for a person named: Harry, Ron because that's what is in the database under friends. How should I fix this?

Posts.php

```
<?php
$friend = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($friend)) {
$channel_name = $row['friend_array'];
}
?>
 <div style="margin-top:120px;">
<?php
$posts = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT content FROM wgo WHERE Posted_By='$channel_name' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)) {
$channel_name2 = $row['content'];
?><div id="rpc"><br/><?php echo" $channel_name2";?></div>
<?php
} 

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question / issue is?

Comment: For me you need to review a little the relations on the Database. I see and aknowledge your n:n connection between friends, however, for me, you need to have a table, a "duplicate" where there are the last example 10 post from each users. First, you need to take all the friends from db, like, SELECT friend_array FROM users, etc, you've already done this, after that, you can show the last 10 posts from each friends of his list.

Comment: Issue: When I query the database for friends, the friends are in the database like this: John,Henry,Lilah, all in the same column so it views that as one friend. See, the friends are all inserted in one cell, so when I query it, it sees it as John,Henry,Lilah as one individual person instead of multiple people, and since there is no one named John,Henry,Lilah, the posts are left blank, when what I want is posts from John AND Henry AND Lilah.

Comment: When you add someone as a friend and the click accept, their name goes into your 'friends' column, so all your friends are in one row. (Sorry, I meant row in my previous comment.

Comment: Eek! You appear to have deleted your recent question about [a friend system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820925/flawed-friend-system). It was getting some downvotes, but hopefully you could see why - questions must contain everything required to be able to answer it (such as a database schema) and have some initially debugging to narrow down the problem. Don't be put off, ask it again, but with those things added in.

Comment: Thanks so much, halfer, you have been so helpful, :D I fixed the problem, and since the question probably wouldn't help other people I deleted it. Thank you so much though for your patience and help. I really really appreciate it. Thanks again! Have a great night! (Or day, wherever you live :D). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really rework how your database is structured. Since a friends list has the potential to be extremely big it needs its own table. But this is how you can get it to work using the current structure:

```
$friends =  explode(',', $friends);

foreach($friends as $friend){
  //do your query for each friend
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your database. The friends should not go into 1 column, but rather a separate table, something like this:

**Table 1**

```
Users:
Id  Username
1   You
2   Harry
3   Ron
```

**Table 2**

```
Friends:
PrimaryId  FriendId
1          2
1          3
```

This is the correct way to do it. There is always parsing to get the job done, but I would highly suggest that you do not go that route in this situation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wish I could upvote you I appreciate it so much! :D